# How to include html attributes in an asp button that is run at server?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, button, html

I want to **add some html attributes to dynamically created asp buttons** using c# so that i can use them to interact with the buttons using jquery.
I basically need to have class and rel as attributes of my buttons in the html of my rendered page.

I am a beginner at using jquery and do not have much knowledge about how to use jquery with my dynamically created asp buttons.

Comment: Use jQuery to do what?

Answer (score 0):

to add  attributes in jquery you can use [attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

```
 $('#elementsID').attr('rel','thisrel');
```

> this add attribute `rel="thisrel"` to a element with `id=elementsID`

to add class you can use [addClass()](http://api.jquery.com/addclass/)

```
$('#elementsID').addClass('newClass');
```

> this adds `class="newClass"` to element with `id=elementsID`

Answer (score 0):

There a "cssClass" attribute in asp button, so you can assign a class name and access that button with the classname with jquery. Else you can see the generated id of the button which is a big value, but it will remain contstant no matter how many times you run the code.